# footer is reapeating in body in last page

Tags: html, doc

i am generating a word doc. but in the last page footer is displaying in body and footer. i am using the code given bellow

```
    <apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="BES_Quote_DOC" contentType="application/msWord" cache="true" standardStylesheets="false">

<head>
<style>
@page {mso-footer:f1;}
div.Section1{page:Section1;}

p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
tab-stops:center 216.0pt right 432.0pt;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="Section1">
  <apex:form id="hidDiv"> 
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>efgh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ijkl</td>
        <td>mnop</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>qrst</td>
        <td>uvwx</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </apex:form>


    <div style="mso-element:footer" id="f1">
        <p class='MsoFooter' align="left" style="font-size: 10px">this is footer</p>
    </div> 
</div>
  </body>

</apex:page>
```

i dont want the footer in body . what should i do.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you got this code and embedded it directly to your file. The headers and footers should be placed in a separate file. This link enabled me to understand more of how headers and footers should be placed. 
[http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation][1]